# Getting socketTimeOut exception while soap parsing

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am calling chartlyrics api for getting lyrics text. But sometime it goes all fine and some time it gives `socketTimeout exception`. i am using following code

```
      try {


        String SOAP_NAMESPACE = "http://api.chartlyrics.com/";
        String SOAP_METHOD = "GetLyric";
        String SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_NAMESPACE + SOAP_METHOD;
        String url = "http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx?op=GetLyric";

        SoapObject requestCode = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD);
        requestCode.addProperty("lyricId", Integer.valueOf(lyricsId));
        requestCode.addProperty("lyricCheckSum", lyricsCheckSum);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestCode);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

//          AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(url);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url, 1000*60*5);

        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        String responseDump = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

        return responseDump;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting this exception at this line

`androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

Any solution will be great help.

Comment: the solution is to check the server or make sure you have decent internet connection

Comment: are you sure from your url=http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx?op=GetLyric? i pasted it in the browser and it is an html page. Where is the WSDL?

Comment: @shadesco ya it's correct url. i am getting all information when i paste it into browser.